# ImportError: No module named Rpi.GPIO

Tags: python, pi-3, rpi.gpio

I use Raspberry Pi 3, model B.

I have installed Rpi.GPIO 0.6.2 successfully from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO

Then I tried to `import Rpi.GPIO as GPIO` but it says:

```
ImportError: No module named Rpi.GPIO
```

What should I do?

Comment: Try `import RPi.GPIO as GPIO` mind the cap P in RPi not Rpi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that in this particular case it is just a minor typo. Instead of `import Rpi.GPIO as GPIO` it should read `import RPi.GPIO as GPIO` as Python is case sensitive.

Another common problem could be installing the Python 2.7 or 3.x version of RPi.GPIO using either `pip2` or `pip3` and then later not running the script with the appropriate version of Python.